# How to export a 2TB table from a RDS instance to S3 or Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, sqoop, rds, dms

I am trying to migrate an entire table from my RDS instance (MySQL 5.7) to either S3 (csv file) or Hive.

The table has a total of 2TB of data. And it has a BLOB column which stores a zip file (usually 100KB, but it can reach 5MB).

I made some tests with Spark, Sqoop and AWS DMS, but had problems with all of them. I have no experience exporting data from RDS with those tools, so I really appreciate any help.

Which one is the most recommended for this task? And what strategy do you think is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the RDS data to S3 using AWS pipeline. Here is an [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copyrdstos3.html) which does the very thing.

Once you taken the dump to S3 in csv format it is easy to read the data using spark and register that as Hive Table.

```
val df = spark.read.csv("s3://...")
df.saveAsTable("mytable") // saves as hive
```